# fileOutputStream() gives either File Not Found or Not A Directory Error

Tags: java, android

`imName` is a string that is not empty.

```
                    File f = new File(getFilesDir().toString(),"myP");
                    if(!f.isDirectory())
                    {
                        f.mkdirs();
                    }
                    File fff=new File(f,imName);
                    //fff.createNewFile();
                    System.out.println("fff.getPath "+fff.getAbsolutePath());
                    FileOutputStream fo = new FileOutputStream(fff);
```

`FileOutputStream fo = new FileOutputStream(fff);` gives error as shown below.

```
2020-05-01 16:12:18.522 13253-13253/com.example.testingproject W/System.err: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/user/0/com.example.testingproject/files/myP/jpg_20200501_1612009_.jpg (Not a directory)
2020-05-01 16:12:18.522 13253-13253/com.example.testingproject W/System.err:     at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method)
2020-05-01 16:12:18.523 13253-13253/com.example.testingproject W/System.err:     at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:221)
2020-05-01 16:12:18.523 13253-13253/com.example.testingproject W/System.err:     at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:169)
2020-05-01 16:12:18.523 13253-13253/com.example.testingproject W/System.err:     at com.example.testingproject.MainActivity.onActivityResult(MainActivity.java:79)
2020-05-01 16:12:18.525 13253-13253/com.example.testingproject W/System.err:     at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:6915)
2020-05-01 16:12:18.525 13253-13253/com.example.testingproject W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4049)
2020-05-01 16:12:18.526 13253-13253/com.example.testingproject W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:4096)
2020-05-01 16:12:18.526 13253-13253/com.example.testingproject W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap20(ActivityThread.java)
2020-05-01 16:12:18.526 13253-13253/com.example.testingproject W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1516)
2020-05-01 16:12:18.528 13253-13253/com.example.testingproject W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
2020-05-01 16:12:18.528 13253-13253/com.example.testingproject W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
2020-05-01 16:12:18.528 13253-13253/com.example.testingproject W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
2020-05-01 16:12:18.529 13253-13253/com.example.testingproject W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
2020-05-01 16:12:18.529 13253-13253/com.example.testingproject W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866)
2020-05-01 16:12:18.531 13253-13253/com.example.testingproject W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756)
```

System out print : `fff.getPath /data/user/0/com.example.testingproject/files/myP/jpg_20200501_1612009_.jpg`

The file exists, and so does the folder. Sometimes the error says the location is not a directory. What could be the issue?

Comment: If `f` exists and isn't a directory, calling `mkdirs()` on it will *fail,* not magically turn it into a directory: and anything subsequent that relies on it being a directory will also fail.

Comment: @user207421 How does something exist, without being part of a directory ?

Comment: @AdityaRewari I didn't say any anything about 'being part of' anything. Read what I wrote.